# Flaws in algorithm and algorithm performance

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, memory-management

```
char *stringmult(int n)
{
    char *x = "hello ";
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        char *y = new char[strlen(x) * 2];
        strcpy(y,x);
        strcat(y,x);
        delete[] x;
        x=y;
    }
    return x;
}
```

I'm trying to figure out what the flaws of this segment is.  For one, it deletes x and then tries to copy it's values over to y.  Another is that y is twice the size of x and that y never gets deleted. Is there anything that I'm missing? And also, I need to figure out how to get algorithm performance.  If you've got a quick link where you learned how, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Please post the complete code.

Comment: Sweet Zombie Jesus that is evil code.

Comment: @Earwicker: That makes it 'C with Classes'. I wouldn't call this C++ at all.

Comment: @rlbond: Putting everything under `static void main(String[])` in Java won't make it C; use C++ like C don't make it less C++.

Comment: This evil code will be very useful for job interviews. It's just great.

Comment: @sharptooth: It would make the kind of hacker code job interview that I truly, sincerely hate.

Comment: @Daniel: why? The code is perfectly readable and quite short. I believe a person why claims he knows C++ well should be able to detect all the drawbacks and errors in such a snippet. Otherwise how do I know he doesn't write C# in C++?

Comment: char * instead of string; strlen _inside a []_!!; non-obvious new and delete; no documentation; non-obvious variable naming; no preconditions; unclear caller/function ownership semantics; I already have a headache without being able to tell what's going on. Nasty. Ugly. Wrong. (By the way, if a 12-line snippet is so readable, why is the poster asking instead of finding out himself?)

Comment: I guess he doesn't have enough knowledge yet. Also some drawbacks like the unclear ownership you mention and undefined behaviour class errors ae not that easy to detect in testing.

Answer (score 5):

`y` needs one more byte than `strlen(x) * 2` to make space for the terminating nul character -- just for starters.

Anyway, as you're returning a `new`ed memory area, it's up to the caller to delete it (eek).

What you're missing, it seems to me, is `std::string`...!-)

As for performance, copying N characters with strcpy is O(N); concatenating N1 characters to a char array with a previous strlen of N2 is O(N1+N2) (std::string is faster as it keeps the length of the string in an O(1)-accessible attribute!-).  So just sum N+N**2 for N up to whatever your limit of interest is (you can ignore the `N+` part if all you want is a big-O estimate since it's clearly going to drop away for larger and larger values of N!-).

Comment: Even more "eek"; When called with n=0 caller *shouldn't* delete it. :-)

Answer (score 3):

For starters delete[] x; operates for the first time round the loop on some static memory. Not good.

It looks like an attempt to return a buffer containing 2^n copies of the string "hello ". So the fastest way to do that would be to figure out the number of copies, then allocate a big enough buffer for the whole result, then fill it with the content and return it.

```
void repeat_string(const std::string &str, int count, std::vector<char> &result)
{
    result.resize(str.size() * count);
    for (int n = 0; n < count; n++)
        str.copy(&result[n * s.size()], s.size());
}

void foo(int power, std::vector<char> &result)
{
    repeat_string("hello ", 1 << (power + 1), result); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. no need to call strlen() in a loop - only call it once;
2. when new is called no space is requested for the null-character - will cause undefined  behaviour;
3. should use strcpy instead of strcat - you already know where to copy the second string and findig the end of string by strcat requires extra computation;
4. delete[] is used on a statically allocated string literal - will cause undefined behaviour;
5. memory is constantly reallocated although you know the result length well in advance - memory reallocation is quite expensive

You should instead compute the result length at once and allocate memory at once and pass the char* as an in-parameter:

```
char* stringMult(const char* what, int n)
{
     const size_t sourceLen = strlen( what );
     int i;
     size_t resultLen = sourceLen;
     // this computation can be done more cleverly and faster
     for( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        resultLen *= 2;
     }
     const int numberOfCopies = resultLen / sourceLen;
     char* result = new char[resultLen + 1];
     char* whereToWrite = result;
     for( i = 0; i < numberOfCopies; i++ ) {
        strcpy( whereToWrite, what );
        whereToWrite += sourceLen;
     }
     return result;
}
```

Certain parts of my implementation can be optimized but still it is much better and (I hope) contains no undefined-behaviour class errors.

Answer (score 1):

you have to add one while allocating space for Y for NULL terminating string
Check the code at below location http://codepad.org/tkGhuUDn

Comment: hmmm.. char * target = malloc(source_len*m+1) * sizeof(char));

Answer (score 0):

```
char * stringmult (int n)
{
    int i;
    size_t m;
    for (i = 0, m = 1; i < n; ++i; m *= 2);
    char * source = "hello ";
    int source_len = strlen(source);
    char * target = malloc(source_len*m+1) * sizeof(char));
    char * tmp = target;
    for (i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        strcpy(tmp, source);
        tmp += source_len;
    }
    *tmp = '\0';
    return target;
}
```

Here a better version in plain C. Most of the drawbacks of your code have been eliminated, i.e. deleting a non-allocated pointer, too many uses of *strlen* and *new*.
Nonetheless, my version may imply the same memory leak as your version, as the caller is responsible to free the string afterwards.

Edit: corrected my code, thanks to sharptooth.

Comment: That will replicate the string n times and the OP's code replicates it 2^n times.

Comment: And you call strlen and strcpy too often - this can be done much much faster.

Comment: Much better except that you should use size_t for the "number of elements" variables. Otherwise this code in unportable.

Comment: That's true, you have to call strcpy only n times, but the underlying copying takes the same time, since the strings will become bigger. It depends on the cost of calling *strcpy* if it is needed to further optimize the code.

Answer (score 0):

char* string_mult(int n)

{

```
const char* x = "hello ";

char* y;

    int i;



for (i = 0; i < n; i++)

{

    if ( i == 0)

    {

        y = (char*) malloc(strlen(x)*sizeof(char));

        strcpy(y, x);

    }

    else

    {

        y = (char*)realloc(y, strlen(x)*(i+1));

        strcat(y, x);

    }

}

return y;
```

}

Comment: This hurts my eyes -- put the special case outside the loop and run from 1 to n instead :)

Answer (score 0):

Nobody is going to point out that "`y`" is in fact being deleted?

Not even one reference to [Schlmeiel the Painter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_painter%27s_Algorithm)?

But the first thing I'd do with this algorithm is:

```
int l = strlen(x);
int log2l = 0;
int log2n = 0;
int ncopy = n;
while (log2l++, l >>= 1);
while (log2n++, n >>= 1);
if (log2l+log2n >= 8*(sizeof(void*)-1)) {
    cout << "don't even bother trying, you'll run out of virtual memory first";
}
```

Comment: Emm... Where? x is being deleted, then y is copied into x.

Comment: @sharptooth: Exactly, so in the next iteration guess what was x... Bingo! the y from the previous iteration! Don't bother to say that then there would be a leak in the last, because that's the memory being returned.

Comment: Nope, on the next iteration y will be attached to a newly allocated memory block, then x will be deleted, y will be copied into x. This thing works fine. And there's no leak until the caller forgets to free memory.

Comment: Nope what? x and y are pointers, so doing y = new...; x = y; delete x; effectively deletes the memory that was allocated for y. I cannot see your point.

Comment: That would be the case if x=y was done before delete, but in the OP's code first delete is done, then x=y.

Comment: Sigh... and that's enclosed in a loop, so for the rest of iterations the value of x is preserved because it's declared outside the loop. Please look more carefully the code and try to understand it before making wrong statements.

Comment: The value of x is changed by the assignment in each loop iteration - it is preserved and that's exactly why this thing would work if other problems haven't stepped in. I suggest you try this on paper.